# Keep list item behavior with onclick attribute

Tags: html, css, razor, onclick, listitem

I have an unordered list (ul) that highlights the listitems (li) when you scroll over them. I added an onclick attribute to the listitem and now it no longer highlights when scrolled over.

My Code:

```
<ul class='sub-menu'>
                        <li onclick="location.href='here'">HERE</li>
                        <li>THERE</li></ul>
```

I used:

```
<td>
                            @Html.ListBoxFor(model => items, items1, new { @size = "20"})
                        </td>
```

To create the list in the .cshtml View

Help?

Comment: Can you post your full code please?

Comment: show your CSS / javascript,  it's impossible to guess

Comment: Its a big project I inherited... Lots of code, multiple .css and .js files being referenced.  Am hoping to create a pseudo-element or use inline .css to override what I am unable to find at this time.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to understand your problem with given information and generated a fiddle Demo below.

[Demo][1]

```
[1]: https://jsfiddle.net/Bhannur/grephvp8/8/
```

As the list items will be of type hyperlink, I have generated above example using anchor tag and setting its properties in css file.

Let me know if this is similar to what you are looking for.